# eventlistener javascript problems

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript and at the moment and I am working on AddEventListener.

What I'm trying to do is to add a new row and so far it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .colorOrange {
            background-color: orange;
        }

        .colorBlue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .colorYellow {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .colorGray {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .colorRed {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .colorGreen {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .colorWhite {
            background-color: white;
        }

        #main {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 325px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .row {
            width: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: block;
        }

        .hideButton, .mainText, .deleteButton {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: inline;
        }
        .btn {

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="main">
        <div class="AddBtn btn">Add</div>
        <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="text till ruta" />

    </div>
    <script>
        var rownr = 0;

        function addListeners() {
            var addButton = document.getElementsByClassName('AddBtn');
            for (var i = 0; i < addButton.length; i++) {
                var addBtn = addButton[i];
                addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var elBtn = event.srcElement;
                    var valueBtn = elBtn.textContent;
                    alert(valueBtn);

                    hideOrShow();
                    addRow();

                    function addRow() {
                        switch (valueBtn) {
                            case "Add":

                                var input = document.getElementById('txtBox').value;
                                rownr++;

                                var div = document.createElement('div');
                                div.className = "row";
                                document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

                                var div2 = document.createElement('div');
                                div2.className = "hideButton colorGreen";
                                var tx = document.createTextNode("<");
                                div2.appendChild(tx);
                                div2.addEventListener('click', hideOrShow, false);
                                div.appendChild(div2);

                                var div3 = document.createElement("div");
                                if (input.toLowerCase() == "red") {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorRed";
                                }
                                else if (input.toLowerCase() == "orange") {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorOrange";
                                }
                                else if (input.toLowerCase() == "blue") {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorBlue";
                                }
                                else if (input.toLowerCase() == "yellow") {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorYellow";
                                }
                                else if (input.toLowerCase() == "gray") {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorGray";
                                } else {
                                    div3.className = "mainText colorWhite";
                                }
                                tx = document.createTextNode(rownr + " " + input);
                                div3.appendChild(tx);
                                div.appendChild(div3);

                                var div4 = document.createElement("div");
                                div4.className = "deleteButton colorRed";
                                tx = document.createTextNode("X");
                                div4.appendChild(tx);
                                //div4.addEventListener('click', deleBtn, false);
                                div.appendChild(div4);

                                var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                                div.appendChild(linebreak);
                            default:
                        }
                    }
```

So far everything works as I want it to do. But when I click on "<" it will go in to this function and find all tags with the hideButton class in it.
The first click it won't find anything, but the second time it will find the "<" value and an alert window will popup and show the value. Here is where I
get lost and can't get it to work.  When you click the the third time it will 
loop or whatever to call it - anyway it will show the alert window 2 times and
then if you repeat the same click it will do the same thing 3 times and so it goes.

```
                    function hideOrShow() {
                        var hideButton = document.getElementsByClassName('hideButton');
                        for (var j = 0; j < hideButton.length; j++) {
                            hideBtn = hideButton[j];
                            hideBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                                var hideElBtn = event.srcElement;
                                var valueHideBtn = hideElBtn.textContent;
                                alert(valueHideBtn);
                            }, false);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        } 
        window.onload = addListeners;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal with this exercise is that

- when you click add button add the text from the input field and add that text to the new row.
- and "<" shall hide the row and change it to ">" to show it again
- and "X" shall just delete the row.

But what I need help with is finding the value part that I mentioned above.

Comment: Your error lies in your `hideOrShow` function. You already have an event listener on your hideButton, but you loop through and add a second event listener in that function, the second even listener you add selects the textContent. You can do away with that event listener and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my rework of your javascript. I explained my solution in your comment, but it may be a bit more clear if illustrated.

In the `addListeners` function, I removed the `hideOrShow` call as it shouldn't be called in the add button.

Next, I removed the for loop in the `hideOrShow` method as you really are only after the caller. I also removed the `addEventListener` call in the same method as you already have an event listener on that element, so there's no need to add one again.

```
    var rownr = 0;
    function addListeners() {
        var addButton = document.getElementsByClassName('AddBtn');
        for (var i = 0; i < addButton.length; i++) {
            var addBtn = addButton[i];
            addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                var elBtn = event.srcElement;
                var valueBtn = elBtn.textContent;
                alert(valueBtn);

                //hideOrShow();
                addRow();

                function addRow() {
                    switch (valueBtn) {
                        case "Add":

                            var input = document.getElementById('txtBox').value;
                            rownr++;

                            var div = document.createElement('div');
                            div.className = "row";
                            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

                            var div2 = document.createElement('div');
                            div2.className = "hideButton colorGreen";
                            var tx = document.createTextNode("<");
                            div2.appendChild(tx);
                            div2.addEventListener('click', hideOrShow, false);
                            div.appendChild(div2);
                            var div3 = document.createElement("div");
                            if (input.toLowerCase() == "red") {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorRed";
                            }
                            else if (input.toLowerCase() == "orange") {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorOrange";
                            }
                            else if (input.toLowerCase() == "blue") {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorBlue";
                            }
                            else if (input.toLowerCase() == "yellow") {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorYellow";
                            }
                            else if (input.toLowerCase() == "gray") {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorGray";
                            } else {
                                div3.className = "mainText colorWhite";
                            }
                            tx = document.createTextNode(rownr + " " + input);
                            div3.appendChild(tx);
                            div.appendChild(div3);

                            var div4 = document.createElement("div");
                            div4.className = "deleteButton colorRed";
                            tx = document.createTextNode("X");
                            div4.appendChild(tx);
                            //div4.addEventListener('click', deleBtn, false);
                            div.appendChild(div4);

                            var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                            div.appendChild(linebreak);
                        default:
                    }
                }
               function hideOrShow() {
                    var hideButton = document.getElementsByClassName('hideButton');
                    var hideElBtn = event.srcElement;
                    var valueHideBtn = hideElBtn.textContent;
                    alert(valueHideBtn);
                }
            }, false);
        }
    } 
    window.onload = addListeners;
```

Comment: ok. so that was why it acted that way, im really great full that you took the time and showed me what i was doing wrong. so i can move forward keep learning more about javascript.